# How can I ensure that /dev/sdd & /dev/sde always map to the same drives each time the Linux machine starts?

Tags: linux, iscsi

OS: Linux 2.6.18 (RedHat-based distro)

I am transitioning from one iSCSI NAS to another iSCSI NAS.  I have them both connected so that I can transfer data.  However, each time I reboot the NAS that maps to /dev/sdd may change; sometimes it's the old one, sometimes it's the new one.  Is there a way that I can set this to be consistent between reboots?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The names of entries in `/dev` are determined by [udev](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html). Find some distinguishing characteristic such as the serial number, then add rules like the following:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTR{vendor}=="Yoyodine", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="123-abc", NAME=="sdd"
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTR{vendor}=="Yoyodine", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="123-def", NAME=="sde"
```

On Debian, you would add these in a file in the directory `/etc/udev/rules.d/`, for example `/etc/udev/rules.d/mydisks.rules`. I think most distributions use this location.

You can use `ATTR`, `ENV` and other criteria to match a device (see the udev documentation for the full list of possibilities). Run `udevinfo -a -n /dev/sdz` when the drive is available as `/dev/sdz` to see what attributes it has. An `ATTR` attribute matches the device itself; there is also `ATTRS` to match an attribute of a parent device (e.g. the bus to which a device is connected). Beware that you can only use `ATTRS` rules from a single section of the `udevinfo` input; in addition, you can use `ATTR` rules from the initial section. See [Understand output of `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45791/understand-output-of-udevadm-info-a-n-dev-sdb for more background).

While you're at it, you might as well give more expressive names such as `old-nas` and `new-nas`.

Comment: Add a line or two about how to find those details?

Comment: @T.C. Good point, edited.